# Deploying Mulesoft Application using Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

I am new to Azure Devops and Mulesoft and I have a requiremet Deploying the Mulesoft application. Could anyone help me creating the Step by step way of deploying the mulesoft application to Cloudhub using Azure devops?

Thanks,
Sreenivas Kaushik

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let us know if you would like further assistance.

Answer (score 1):

In order to deploy applications using Azure basically you need to follow these steps:

1. Create a project and repository in Azure
2. Push your Mulesoft code to the repo (your project should be based on maven and should contain a POM.xml and settings file, POM contains all dependencies and repositories where the dependencies would be pulled, settings.xml will allow to define the server credentials and repos to authenticate).
3. On Azure, locate the pipeline section, create a new pipeline for maven project, copy and paste the content and add new file to your mule root project (will post a sample file of how should be)
4. Create a new artifact connection in azure, this will generate server credentials for the settings.xml file and the POM repository information.

5.Update you settings and pom files in your mule project.

6. Adapt you POM.xml and settings.

Here a POM.xml sample

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>abi-wiit-orderandcoolfix2</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>mule</packaging>
    <name>YOUR_PROJECT_NAME</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <mule.version>3.9.2</mule.version>
        <mule.tools.version>1.7</mule.tools.version>
    </properties>

    <scm>
        <connection>scm:git:SSH_PATH_OF_YOUR_REPOSITORY</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:SSH_PATH_OF_YOUR_REPOSITORY</developerConnection>
        <url>URL_OF_YOUR_REPOSITORY</url>
    </scm>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mule.tools.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>mule-app-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${mule.tools.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <copyToAppsDirectory>true</copyToAppsDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-resource</id>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-resource</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/app/</directory>
                                </resource>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/api/</directory>
                                </resource>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>mappings/</directory>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <!--this will be the propfile to deploy your app to cloudhub-->
        <profile>
            <id>deploy-cloudhub-dev</id>
            <build>
                <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${scmBranch}-r${buildNumber}</finalName>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.4</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>validate</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>create</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <doCheck>true</doCheck>
                            <doUpdate>false</doUpdate>
                            <shortRevisionLength>7</shortRevisionLength>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.mule.tools.maven</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mule-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.2.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <deploymentType>cloudhub</deploymentType>
                            <!-- muleVersion is the runtime version as it appears on the CloudHub interface -->
                            <muleVersion>${mule.version}</muleVersion>
                            <username>${anypoint.username}</username>
                            <password>${anypoint.password}</password>
                            <redeploy>true</redeploy>
                            <environment>Development</environment>
                            <applicationName>${artifactId}</applicationName>
                            <!--<region>eu-central-1</region>-->
                            <workerType>Micro</workerType>
                            <workers>${test.workers}</workers>
                            <properties>
                                <env>${env}</env>
                            </properties>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>deploy</id>
                                <phase>deploy</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>deploy</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <!-- Mule Dependencies -->
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Xml configuration -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-core-ee</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Xml configuration -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-spring-config-ee</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Mule Transports -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-file</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-http</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-jdbc-ee</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-jms-ee</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-vm</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Mule Modules -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-scripting</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-xml</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- for testing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.tests</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-tests-functional</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-apikit</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-security-property-placeholder</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-sfdc</artifactId>
            <version>8.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-spring-config</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-email</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.weave</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-plugin-weave</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-json</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
         <repository>
            <id>mule-ee-releases</id>
            <name>MuleEE Releases Repository</name>
            <url>https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus-ee/content/repositories/releases-ee/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
       <id>mulesoft-releases</id>
           <name>MuleSoft Releases Repository</name>
           <url>http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
           <layout>default</layout>
       </repository>
       <repository>
           <id>mulesoft-snapshots</id>
           <name>MuleSoft Snapshots Repository</name>
           <url>http://repository.mulesoft.org/snapshots/</url>
           <layout>default</layout>
       </repository>

        <!--HERE THE REPOSITORY URL GENERATED BY AZURE-->
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>mulesoft-release</id>
            <name>mulesoft release repository</name>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <url>http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>

    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

Here the Settings.xml file sample

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>



<!--

Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one

or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file

distributed with this work for additional information

regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file

to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the

"License"); you may not use this file except in compliance

with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at



    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0



Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,

software distributed under the License is distributed on an

"AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY

KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the

specific language governing permissions and limitations

under the License.

-->



<!--

| This is the configuration file for Maven. It can be specified at two levels:

|

|  1. User Level. This settings.xml file provides configuration for a single user,

|                 and is normally provided in ${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml.

|

|                 NOTE: This location can be overridden with the CLI option:

|

|                 -s /path/to/user/settings.xml

|

|  2. Global Level. This settings.xml file provides configuration for all Maven

|                 users on a machine (assuming they're all using the same Maven

|                 installation). It's normally provided in

|                 ${maven.conf}/settings.xml.

|

|                 NOTE: This location can be overridden with the CLI option:

|

|                 -gs /path/to/global/settings.xml

|

| The sections in this sample file are intended to give you a running start at

| getting the most out of your Maven installation. Where appropriate, the default

| values (values used when the setting is not specified) are provided.

|

|-->

<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"

          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

  <!-- localRepository

   | The path to the local repository maven will use to store artifacts.

   |

   | Default: ${user.home}/.m2/repository

  <localRepository>/path/to/local/repo</localRepository>

  -->



  <!-- interactiveMode

   | This will determine whether maven prompts you when it needs input. If set to false,

   | maven will use a sensible default value, perhaps based on some other setting, for

   | the parameter in question.

   |

   | Default: true

  <interactiveMode>true</interactiveMode>

  -->



  <!-- offline

   | Determines whether maven should attempt to connect to the network when executing a build.

   | This will have an effect on artifact downloads, artifact deployment, and others.

   |

   | Default: false

  <offline>false</offline>

  -->



  <!-- pluginGroups

   | This is a list of additional group identifiers that will be searched when resolving plugins by their prefix, i.e.

   | when invoking a command line like "mvn prefix:goal". Maven will automatically add the group identifiers

   | "org.apache.maven.plugins" and "org.codehaus.mojo" if these are not already contained in the list.

   |-->

  <pluginGroups>

    <!-- pluginGroup

     | Specifies a further group identifier to use for plugin lookup.

    <pluginGroup>com.your.plugins</pluginGroup>

    -->

  </pluginGroups>



  <!-- proxies

   | This is a list of proxies which can be used on this machine to connect to the network.

   | Unless otherwise specified (by system property or command-line switch), the first proxy

   | specification in this list marked as active will be used.

   |-->

  <proxies>

    <!-- proxy

     | Specification for one proxy, to be used in connecting to the network.

     |

    <proxy>

      <id>optional</id>

      <active>true</active>

      <protocol>http</protocol>

      <username>proxyuser</username>

      <password>proxypass</password>

      <host>proxy.host.net</host>

      <port>80</port>

      <nonProxyHosts>local.net|some.host.com</nonProxyHosts>

    </proxy>

    -->

  </proxies>



  <!-- servers

   | This is a list of authentication profiles, keyed by the server-id used within the system.

   | Authentication profiles can be used whenever maven must make a connection to a remote server.

   |-->

  <servers>

    <!-- server

     | Specifies the authentication information to use when connecting to a particular server, identified by

     | a unique name within the system (referred to by the 'id' attribute below).

     |

     | NOTE: You should either specify username/password OR privateKey/passphrase, since these pairings are

     |       used together.

     |

    <server>

      <id>deploymentRepo</id>

      <username>repouser</username>

      <password>repopwd</password>

    </server>

    -->



    <!-- Another sample, using keys to authenticate.

    <server>

      <id>siteServer</id>

      <privateKey>/path/to/private/key</privateKey>

      <passphrase>optional; leave empty if not used.</passphrase>

    </server>

    -->



    <server>

        <id>MuleRepository</id>

        <username>nexus</username>

        <password></password>

    </server>


    <!-- HERE THE CREDENTIALS GENERATED AFTER CONNECT THEW ARTIFACT -->




  </servers> 



  <!-- mirrors

   | This is a list of mirrors to be used in downloading artifacts from remote repositories.

   |

   | It works like this: a POM may declare a repository to use in resolving certain artifacts.

   | However, this repository may have problems with heavy traffic at times, so people have mirrored

   | it to several places.

   |

   | That repository definition will have a unique id, so we can create a mirror reference for that

   | repository, to be used as an alternate download site. The mirror site will be the preferred

   | server for that repository.

   |-->

  <mirrors>

    <!-- mirror

     | Specifies a repository mirror site to use instead of a given repository. The repository that

     | this mirror serves has an ID that matches the mirrorOf element of this mirror. IDs are used

     | for inheritance and direct lookup purposes, and must be unique across the set of mirrors.

     |

    <mirror>

      <id>mirrorId</id>

      <mirrorOf>repositoryId</mirrorOf>

      <name>Human Readable Name for this Mirror.</name>

      <url>http://my.repository.com/repo/path</url>

    </mirror>

     -->

  </mirrors>



  <!-- profiles

   | This is a list of profiles which can be activated in a variety of ways, and which can modify

   | the build process. Profiles provided in the settings.xml are intended to provide local machine-

   | specific paths and repository locations which allow the build to work in the local environment.

   |

   | For example, if you have an integration testing plugin - like cactus - that needs to know where

   | your Tomcat instance is installed, you can provide a variable here such that the variable is

   | dereferenced during the build process to configure the cactus plugin.

   |

   | As noted above, profiles can be activated in a variety of ways. One way - the activeProfiles

   | section of this document (settings.xml) - will be discussed later. Another way essentially

   | relies on the detection of a system property, either matching a particular value for the property,

   | or merely testing its existence. Profiles can also be activated by JDK version prefix, where a

   | value of '1.4' might activate a profile when the build is executed on a JDK version of '1.4.2_07'.

   | Finally, the list of active profiles can be specified directly from the command line.

   |

   | NOTE: For profiles defined in the settings.xml, you are restricted to specifying only artifact

   |       repositories, plugin repositories, and free-form properties to be used as configuration

   |       variables for plugins in the POM.

   |

   |-->

  <profiles>

    <!-- profile

     | Specifies a set of introductions to the build process, to be activated using one or more of the

     | mechanisms described above. For inheritance purposes, and to activate profiles via <activatedProfiles/>

     | or the command line, profiles have to have an ID that is unique.

     |

     | An encouraged best practice for profile identification is to use a consistent naming convention

     | for profiles, such as 'env-dev', 'env-test', 'env-production', 'user-jdcasey', 'user-brett', etc.

     | This will make it more intuitive to understand what the set of introduced profiles is attempting

     | to accomplish, particularly when you only have a list of profile id's for debug.

     |

     | This profile example uses the JDK version to trigger activation, and provides a JDK-specific repo.

    <profile>

      <id>jdk-1.4</id>



      <activation>

        <jdk>1.4</jdk>

      </activation>



      <repositories>

        <repository>

          <id>jdk14</id>

          <name>Repository for JDK 1.4 builds</name>

          <url>http://www.myhost.com/maven/jdk14</url>

          <layout>default</layout>

          <snapshotPolicy>always</snapshotPolicy>

        </repository>

      </repositories>

    </profile>

    -->



    <!--

     | Here is another profile, activated by the system property 'target-env' with a value of 'dev',

     | which provides a specific path to the Tomcat instance. To use this, your plugin configuration

     | might hypothetically look like:

     |

     | ...

     | <plugin>

     |   <groupId>org.myco.myplugins</groupId>

     |   <artifactId>myplugin</artifactId>

     |

     |   <configuration>

     |     <tomcatLocation>${tomcatPath}</tomcatLocation>

     |   </configuration>

     | </plugin>

     | ...

     |

     | NOTE: If you just wanted to inject this configuration whenever someone set 'target-env' to

     |       anything, you could just leave off the <value/> inside the activation-property.

     |

    <profile>

      <id>env-dev</id>



      <activation>

        <property>

          <name>target-env</name>

          <value>dev</value>

        </property>

      </activation>



      <properties>

        <tomcatPath>/path/to/tomcat/instance</tomcatPath>

      </properties>

    </profile>

    -->



    <profile>



        <id>Mule</id>

        <activation>

            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>

        </activation>

        <repositories>

            <repository>

                <id>MuleRepository</id>

                <name>MuleRepository</name>

                <url>https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus-ee/content/repositories/releases-ee/</url>

                <layout>default</layout>

                <releases>

                    <enabled>true</enabled>

                </releases>

                <snapshots>

                    <enabled>true</enabled>

                </snapshots>

            </repository>



            <!-- HERE THE REPO PROVIDED BY AZURE -->



        </repositories>



    </profile>

  </profiles>



  <!-- activeProfiles

   | List of profiles that are active for all builds.

   |

  <activeProfiles>

    <activeProfile>alwaysActiveProfile</activeProfile>

    <activeProfile>anotherAlwaysActiveProfile</activeProfile>

  </activeProfiles>

  -->

</settings>
```

Finally here the YAML sample

```
# Maven
# Build your Java project and run tests with Apache Maven.
# Add steps that analyze code, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/java

trigger:
- master 
- test

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- task: Maven@3
  inputs:
    mavenPomFile: 'pom.xml'
    mavenOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
    javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
    jdkVersionOption: '1.8'
    jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
    publishJUnitResults: true
    testResultsFiles: '**/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'
    goals: 'clean deploy -P deploy-cloudhub-dev -Danypoint.username=YOUR_ANYPOINT_USERNAME -Danypoint.password=YOUR_ANYPOINT_PASSWORD -Denv=ENVIRONEMNT -s settings.xml -e'

- task: Maven@3
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master'))
  inputs:
    mavenPomFile: 'pom.xml'
    mavenOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
    javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
    jdkVersionOption: '1.8'
    jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
    publishJUnitResults: true
    testResultsFiles: '**/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'
    goals: 'clean install -U -s settings.xml -e'
```

This will kick the process for test branch for deployment after a Pull request is merged from DEV -> TEST, you can filter to run another action to link master (Production).

Hope this helps.

Best

Answer (score 0):

> Could anyone help me creating the Step by step way of deploying the mulesoft application to Cloudhub using Azure devops?

To deploy the mulesoft application to Cloudhub using Azure devops, you could use Mule Maven Plugin to automate deployment on CloudHub by extracting information from POM.

Azure DevOps will initiate the corresponding Maven command to trigger the deployment on CloudHub after application packing is completed.

You can check the document [Deploying a Mule Application to CloudHub Via AWS, Azure, and Jenkins](https://dzone.com/articles/deploying-mule-application-to-cloudhub-via-aws-azu) for some more details.

And how to use Mule Maven Plugin, just check the document [Mule Plugin for Maven](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/3.8/mule-maven-plugin).

Hope this helps.